MariaDB InnoDB Primary Index oc_files_metadata corruption error. Cannot dump (1030 error) Cannot Optimize
I am running Nextcloud in a linuxserver Docker Container with a separate MariaDB docker container. I recently ran into an error in Nextcloud where I was getting
"An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1712 Index oc_files_metadata is corrupted"
Checking the DB I found the below error:
MariaDB [nextcloud]> CHECK TABLE oc_files_metadata;
+-----------------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                       | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text                                               |
+-----------------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| nextcloud.oc_files_metadata | check | Warning  | InnoDB: Index PRIMARY is marked as corrupted           |
| nextcloud.oc_files_metadata | check | Warning  | InnoDB: Index files_meta_fileid is marked as corrupted |
| nextcloud.oc_files_metadata | check | error    | Corrupt                                                |
+-----------------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)

When I try to OPTIMIZE TABLE I get:
MariaDB [nextcloud]> OPTIMIZE TABLE oc_files_metadata;
+-----------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                       | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+-----------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| nextcloud.oc_files_metadata | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| nextcloud.oc_files_metadata | optimize | error    | Got error 106 "Socket is connected" from storage engine InnoDB    |
| nextcloud.oc_files_metadata | optimize | status   | Operation failed                                                  |
+-----------------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (1.989 sec)

When I try to dump the table to reimport I get the below:
root@b03e11e55d8a:/# mariadb-dump -u root -p nextcloud oc_files_metadata > oc_files_metadata_bak-8-5-24.sql
Enter password: 
mariadb-dump: Error 1034: Index for table 'oc_files_metadata' is corrupt; try to repair it when dumping table `oc_files_metadata` at row: 150230

I tried just Deleting that one row ID and that didn't work either. I'm at a loss here.

What happens with REPAIR TABLE oc_files_metadata; ?  Was the table ENGINE=MyISAM?

It's an InnoDB table and won't let me convert to MyISAM due to the corruption
